# javascript - Remove in Array closest values

Tags: javascript, arrays

i try remove neighborhood values in array. The items are moved from one array to another, after which if the two neighboring elements are similar, they must be removed. And so on the chain.
Experience is not enough to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```js
let arr = ["w", "w", "s", "n", "d", "a", "a", "d", "o", "w", "f", "f", "d", "e", "n", "n", "n"];

var unique = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
  return index === self.indexOf(elem);

});

console.log('unique', unique);
```

in OUTPUT: After the second filtering, we get the name of the person!

wrong answers:

> unique (12) ["w", "s", "n", "d", "a", "d", "o", "w", "f", "d", "e", "n"]
>
> unique (5) ["w", "a", "f", "n", "n"]

Comment: You can also use `Array.from(new Set(["w", "w", "s", "n", "d", "a", "a", "d", "o", "w", "f", "f", "d", "e", "n", "n", "n"]));`, BTW what is problem you are facing?

Comment: What is expected output? ["w", "s", "n", "d", "a", "d", "o", "w", "f", "d", "e", "n"]; Maybe this, if i understand correctly?

Comment: @HassanImam is not work sor ;P

Comment: @HassanImam  After the second filtering, we get the name of the person

Comment: Please update the question with the expected output.

Comment: Done, update task

Comment: please add the wanted result. (maybe i should as for a button for this comment.)

Comment: Ok, so this is some code riddle, lol? :D

Comment: Person is snowden... ok...

Comment: Yes, its name of man )), but how get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce`. Inside the loop compare last value inserted with the current value, if same remove the last value otherwise push the new value. The name is `Snowden`.

```js
let arr = ["w", "w", "s", "n", "d", "a", "a", "d", "o", "w", "f", "f", "d", "e", "n", "n", "n"];

var unique = arr.reduce(function(result, elem) {
  if(result[result.length - 1] == elem)
    result.pop();
  else 
    result.push(elem);
  return result;
}, []);

console.log('unique', unique);
```

Comment: Like, its true answer

Comment: Any reason for not using strict equality in your comparison?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Since I was comparing same type of values, so didn't like the idea of comparing with strict equality.

Comment: With such a small code, there won't be any drastic improvement.